# How to analyze heapdump with common leak suspect

Tags: java, object, heap-dump

The application hitting slowness issue and generate some `heapdump` file, the `heapdump` file is 1.2GB, and I need to run my `ha456.jar` using 8.4GB RAM only can open the heapdump.

Before this, when I analyze the `heapdump`, I will try to see the Bigger `LeakSize` and check for the Leak Suspect value, and I can see that which class or which method of my application holding the big memory. And then I will try to fix the code so that it can run with better performance.

For this time, I cant really get the point that which module/method of my application causing the out of memory issue. The following are some of my screen shot of my `HeapAnalyzer`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For me, its just common class, for example java/lang/object, java/lang/Long, or java/util/HashMap. I cant really know which method of my application causing the out of memory.

Appreciate your advise on how to analyze on this.

Answer (score 2):

Finding memory leak is always very difficult for anyone in front of the code, let alone from so far. So I can only give you some suggestions:

1. you got an heap dump, filter by your **own objects** and analyze who creates the most numerous
2. run your application and monitor it with VisualVM, use the application a little bit and then force a GC run... 9 times out of 10 the objects whose number does not decrease significantly or do not completely reset are your memory leak

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happening due to a lot of records are read from somewhere like database, queue which is of type Long. There could be a cartesian join or something of that sort. Once i had a ton of strings causing oom and the culprit was a logger accumulating logs.

A couple of thoughts-
When you get oom error trace that back to the suspect method. 
Get thread dump and see which threads are active and what they are executing.